# Should I use "did "or "had" in this question?

Tags: tense, past-tense, questions, past-perfect

My friend called me. I could not pick up his call because I was driving my car. When I reached the office and called him back, I wanted to remind him about his last call. How could I remind him about it?

> Hello, did you call me?  Sorry I was driving my car at that time.

Or

> Hello, Had you called me?  Sorry I was driving my car at that time.

Or I just could say

> Hello, you called me?  Sorry I was driving my car at that time.

Maybe there is a better way to say this?

Comment: Simple Past Did you go to work yesterday? Past Perfect Had you ever left the door unlocked before?

Answer (score 2):

You first need to think about what you want to say as a simple statement rather than as a question. Once you get that right, you can convert it to a question.

> You called me (simple past - before now)

This means that you called me some time before now

> You had called me - (past perfect - before some event in the past)

In your situation, the first is the correct statement.

No let's look at how to turn it into a question. If the main verb in the sentence is **be** or a modal like **can** or **must**, or there is an auxiliary verb like **have** or **will** in front of the main verb, you just switch the word order:

> You are ready.  -> Are you ready?
>
> You have eaten -> Have you eaten?
>
> You will eat -> Will you eat?

In all other situations, you can to use **Do**?

> You called me. -> Did you call me?

You can also ask a question just using inflection:

> You called me?

Looking at your examples, you will see that the first (using **Did**) and third (inflection only) are correct.

The middle one would be correct if you were asking whether he called you **before some event in the past** (**had** is an auxiliary verb so you don't need to use Do), but it is not appropriate for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of posing a question for your friend, how about saying, "*I believe I received a call from you earlier today*." His/her natural response to this would be, "Ah, yes. I did call you regarding..."